# Fibonacci with Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I tried to make a fibonacci generator in Assembly language, using a separate function to display the values in binary (DispBinary), but it looks like the numbers are coming out as 6, 30, 120, etc. Is there something wrong with the order that I have used for imul or did I get eax and ecx switched?

```
  Main: 
         Call DispBinary ;display binary
         Mov Ecx, 6
         Mov Eax, 1
  L1: 
         IMul Eax, Ecx
         Call DispBinary
         Loop L1 
         Xor Eax, Eax
```

Comment: Why are you using imul at all? For the Fibonacci series, the next number is the *sum* of the two previous, not their product.

Comment: Hmm, guess that would make much more sense, thanks. So I take it that this involves a lot more code? Would I store the initial values in registers like Eax and Ecx then loop through and add?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a *lot* more code, but yes: initialize two registers to 1, then add them together to get the next item. As I recall it's often easiest to unroll the loop once (i.e., generate two numbers per iteration of the loop).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code (rcx is represent n ,  n=5)

```
ExitProcess PROTO

.data 

.code

main proc

mov rax,1
mov rbx,0
mov rcx,5
mov rdx,0 
push rdx

L1:
    mov rdx,rax
    add rdx,rbx
    push rdx
    mov rax,rbx
    mov rbx,rdx
    dec rcx
    cmp rcx,00h
    jnz L1
    nop



call ExitProcess

main endp

end
```